# communication between a cpp file and an h file

Tags: c++11, header-files

Please consider the following

```
/*utils.h*/
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
//#include some other files, including <string>
//ifndef ... and such macro
extern string configpath;
extern void writelog(string, string);
extern string get_fromfile(string, string);
//end the said macro
```

then we have

```
/*utils.cpp*/
//all necessary includes, including <string>
#include "utils.h" //they are in the same folder, as the following main .cpp
void writelog(string msg, string location = "lookinconfigfile")
{
if (location == "lookinconfigfile")
  {
    get_fromFile(configpath, "logpath"); 
    //the function correctly returns the path to logfile, tested separatly.
  }
  ...
}
string get_formFile(string flpt, string wht)
{...}
```

then in main.cpp, i include utils.h, and set the configpath to point to a file which holds a path to the logfile.

now `g++ -c utils.cpp -std=c++11` produces utils.o
`g++ -c main.cpp -std=c++11` produces main.o

before introducing the configpath as a global variable, by explicitly mentioning the configpath, that is, hard coding it to each occurrence, i was able to do this:

```
g++ main.o -o main
```

and that would generate main as an executable which would behave as expected.

But now i get this:

```
main.o: In function `writelog(std::string, std::string)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `configpath
```

Also, if i keep the definition of `get_fromFile` in `utils.cpp _after_ writelog`, despite the prototype in utils.h, i get that `get_fromFile is not defined`.

where do i search looking for solutions?

edit: as user2079303 suggested, yes, it is utils.h, not utils.cpp, thank you.

edit2: as bobah mentioned, i actually have the cases correct in my code, just mistyped here. sorry.

Comment: "then in main.cpp, i include utils.cpp" Did you mean include utils.h? If not, that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `define` your variable to let compiler know which object file to put it to. Mentioning it in the header file as `extern string configpath;` just tell compiler that somewhere there will be this variable, leave unresolved reference and let linker resolve it.

Add to your main.cpp:

```
string configpath;
```

Comment: O_O  that solved the issue !! 
what about the failure to find definition of get_fromFile despite the prototype?

Comment: C++ is case sensitive you either have `get_fromfile` or `get_fromFile` in both header and cpp

Comment: uh i notice now that i typed the case wrong in this question, but in actual code, the cases are correct..

Answer (score 0):

In your final invocation to gcc, you only link main.o, but not utils.o.